# Spark Streaming Kafka write output to console OR to Kafka Topic is not working

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to stream data in Spark from kafka through python codes using 2 different machines (1 for kafka used to produce JSON data, and the other used for Spart to stream this data after aggregation),
when streaming the data, it couldn't print to console or being written to another topic. and I used different values for outputmode. and when terminating the code i got the below:

ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/clientserver.py", line 511, in send_command
answer = smart_decode(self.stream.readline()[:-1])
RuntimeError: reentrant call inside <_io.BufferedReader name=3>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

An error occurred while calling o76.awaitTermination

However, same script works with me running kafka and spark on the same machine

`

```
print("Printing Schema of orders_df4: ")
    orders_df4.printSchema()
    # Write final result into console for debugging purpose
    orders_agg_write_stream = orders_df4.writeStream \
        .trigger(processingTime='5 seconds')\
        .outputMode("update")\
        .option("truncate", "false")\
        .format("console")\
        .start()\
        .awaitTermination()
```

`
OR

`

```
    # Write Final RESULT To KAFKA TOPIC in the same machine
   orders_df4.writeStream \
       .outputMode("complete")
       .format("kafka")\
       .option("kafka_bootsrap_servers",kafka_bootsrap_servers)\
       .option("topic",kafka_topic_write)\
       .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")\
        .start()\
       .awaitAnyTermination()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA0vP.png)`